Explode Polars rows on multiple columns but with different logic
I have this code, which splits a product column into a list, and then uses explode to expand it:
import polars as pl
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_3_month_splits(product: str) -> list[str]:
    front, start_dt, total_m = product.rsplit('.', 2)
    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y%m')
    total_m  = int(total_m)
    return [f'{front}.{(start_dt+relativedelta(months=m)).strftime("%Y%m")}.3' for m in range(0, total_m, 3)]

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'product':    ['CHECK.GB.202403.12', 'CHECK.DE.202506.6', 'CASH.US.202509.12'],
    'qty':        [10, -20, 50],
    'price_paid': [1400, -3300, 900],
})

print(df.with_columns(pl.col('product').map_elements(get_3_month_splits, return_dtype=pl.List(str))).explode('product'))

This currently gives
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ product           ┆ qty ┆ price_paid │
│ ---               ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str               ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202406.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202409.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202412.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CHECK.DE.202509.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202512.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202603.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202606.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
└───────────────────┴─────┴────────────┘

However, I want to keep the total price paid the same. So after splitting the rows into several "sub categories", I want to change the table to this:
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ product           ┆ qty ┆ price_paid │
│ ---               ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str               ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202406.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202409.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202412.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CHECK.DE.202509.3 ┆ -20 ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202512.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202603.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202606.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
└───────────────────┴─────┴────────────┘

i.e. only keeping the price_paid in the first expanded row. So my total price paid remains the same. The qty is okay to stay the way it is.
I tried e.g. with_columns(price_arr=pl.col('product').cast(pl.List(pl.Float64))) but was then unable to add anything to first element of the list. Or with_columns(price_arr=pl.col(['product', 'price_paid']).map_elements(price_func)) but it did not seem possible to use map_elements on pl.col([...]).

Concat the appropriate number of trailing 0s to price_paid before calling .explode() on both product and price_paid at once:
print(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.col("product").map_elements(get_3_month_splits, return_dtype=pl.List(str))
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(
            pl.col("price_paid"), pl.lit(0).repeat_by(pl.col("product").list.len() - 1)
        )
    )
    .explode("product", "price_paid")
)

Output:
shape: (10, 3)
┌───────────────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ product           ┆ qty ┆ price_paid │
│ ---               ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str               ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202406.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202409.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202412.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CHECK.DE.202509.3 ┆ -20 ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202512.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202603.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202606.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
└───────────────────┴─────┴────────────┘


you can use is_first_distinct() and when/then:
(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.col.product.alias("group"),
        pl.col.product.map_elements(get_3_month_splits, return_dtype=pl.List(str))
    ).explode("product")
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col.group.is_first_distinct()).then(pl.col.price_paid).otherwise(0)
    ).drop("group")
)

┌───────────────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ product           ┆ qty ┆ price_paid │
│ ---               ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str               ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202406.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202409.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202412.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CHECK.DE.202509.3 ┆ -20 ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202512.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202603.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202606.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
└───────────────────┴─────┴────────────┘

You can also avoid using map_elements() and use pure polars expressions (it's a bit rough but you get the idea):
(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.col.product.str.split('.')
    ).with_columns(
        start_dt = pl.col.product.list.get(2).str.to_datetime("%Y%m"),
        offset = pl.col.product.list.get(3).cast(pl.Int64) - 3
    ).with_columns(
        dates = pl.date_ranges(
            pl.col.start_dt,
            pl.col.start_dt.dt.offset_by(pl.col.offset.cast(pl.String) + "mo"),
            interval="3mo"
        )
    ).explode("dates")
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(
            pl.col.product.list.head(2),
            pl.col.start_dt.dt.strftime("%Y%m"),
            pl.lit(3)
        ).list.join(".")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col.product.is_first_distinct().over("start_dt", "offset")).then(pl.col.price_paid).otherwise(0)
    ).drop("start_dt", "offset", "dates")
)

┌───────────────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ product           ┆ qty ┆ price_paid │
│ ---               ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str               ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 1400       │
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.GB.202403.3 ┆ 10  ┆ 0          │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ -3300      │
│ CHECK.DE.202506.3 ┆ -20 ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 900        │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
│ CASH.US.202509.3  ┆ 50  ┆ 0          │
└───────────────────┴─────┴────────────┘

